# xslt document function question

Tags: xslt

If one is using the document function and opening up files that might not exist e.g.

```
<xsl:variable name="input" select="document($A)/document/input"/>
```

what is the graceful way of handling the error?  I would like a default value for the variable if the file can't be opened.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you can write your `<xsl:variable>` like so:

```
<xsl:variable name="input">
 <xsl:choose>
  <xsl:when test="document($A)/document/testElementCondition = 'foo'">
   <xsl:value-of select="document($A)/document/input" />
  </xsl:when>
  <xsl:otherwise>
   <!-- add some default source document and logic that will then direct to an error message. -->
  </xsl:otherwise>
  </xsl:choose>
</xsl:variable>
```

It is too bad that you often have to result to hacks to get things done in XSL.

Comment: As pointed out in my answer, there is no guarantee that the XSLT Processor will not raise an error (which is allowed by the XSLT Spec.)

Therefore, the above is not a completely correct answer.

Answer (score 7):

**There isn't a general way to handle gracefully an error in the [`document()`](http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt#function-document) function**.

**According to the [XSLT 1.0 spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt#function-document)**:

" *If there is an error retrieving the resource, then the XSLT processor may signal an error; if it does not signal an error, it must recover by returning an empty node-set.* "

**This means that we are at the mercy of the implementor** whether an empty node-set is produced by the function (good, we can test for empty (non-existent) node-set) or "signals an error", which typically may end the transformation.

In case we have checked that a particular implementation of a specific XSLT processor only produces an empty node-set and does not end the transformation, we may decide to test for this condition and "gracefully" recover. However, our application becomes non-portable, it depends on this specific XSLT processor and there is absolutely no guarantee that in the next version this behaviour will not change to the worse one. Risky, isn't it?

**Therefore, it is best that whoever launches the transformation (such as from within a C# program), should check for the existence of the file** and pass an appropriate parameter to the transformation, reflecting this existence.

Answer (score 2):

What about using doc-available() function available in XPath 2.0 ? :
http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-functions/#func-doc-available

Answer (score 0):

The graceful way would be to check file existence before you feed the parameter to your stylesheet.

Comment: It is not really coming from the command line, I just wrote the question that way to make it simple.  (I agree with your comment if it was.)  :-)

It seems like their must be some way of "handling errors" such as this with xslt.