# How do I selectively include elements from one or the other xml file based on the contents of a plain text file?

Tags: xslt, xslt-2.0, saxon

I have two source xml files and I need to construct a new xml file which contains elements chosen for one or other of the files depending on whether their 'name' is contained in a plain text file.

xml file a:

```xml
<data name="name1">
  <value>abc1</value>
</data>
<data name="name2">
  <value>abc2</value>
</data>
<data name="name3">
  <value>abc3</value>
</data>
```

xml file b:

```xml
<data name="name1">
  <value>xyz1</value>
</data>
<data name="name2">
  <value>xyz2</value>
</data>
<data name="name3">
  <value>xyz3</value>
</data>
```

text file:

```xml
name1
name3
```

desired output:

```xml
<data name="name1">
  <value>abc1</value>
</data>
<data name="name2">
  <value>xyz2</value>        <---- note this element is from file 'b'
</data>
<data name="name3">
  <value>abc3</value>
</data>
```

So the elements with names 'name1' and 'name3' come from 'xml file a' because they are listed in the text file, but 'name2' comes from 'xml file b' because it isn't.

The actual names aren't 'name1' etc, but arbitrary string identifiers, but they are unique within the files.

Is it possible to do this with XSLT?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**This transformation**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0"   xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>

    <xsl:variable name="vNames" select=
    "tokenize(unparsed-text('file:///c:/temp/delete/Names.txt'), '\s')"/>

    <xsl:variable name="vDoc1" select="document('file:///c:/temp/delete/FileA.xml')"/>
    <xsl:variable name="vDoc2" select="document('file:///c:/temp/delete/FileB.xml')"/>

 <xsl:template match="/">
     <t>
       <xsl:sequence select=
        "$vDoc1/*/*[@name = $vNames],
         $vDoc2/*/*[not(@name = $vNames)]
        "/>
     </t>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**when applied on any XML document (not used) and having these two files**:

**c:/temp/delete/FileA.xml**:

```
<t>
    <data name="name1">
        <value>abc1</value>
    </data>
    <data name="name2">
        <value>abc2</value>
    </data>
    <data name="name3">
        <value>abc3</value>
    </data>
</t>
```

**c:/temp/delete/FileB.xml**:

```
<t>
    <data name="name1">
        <value>xyz1</value>
    </data>
    <data name="name2">
        <value>xyz2</value>
    </data>
    <data name="name3">
        <value>xyz3</value>
    </data>
</t>
```

**c:/temp/delete/Names.txt**:

```
name1
name3
```

**produces the wanted, correct result:**

```
<t>
   <data name="name1">
            <value>abc1</value>
      </data>
   <data name="name3">
            <value>abc3</value>
      </data>
   <data name="name2">
            <value>xyz2</value>
      </data>
</t>
```

**Explanation**:

Proper use of the standard XSLT functions: **[`unparsed-text()`](http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt20/#function-unparsed-text)** (2.0 and up only) and **[`document()`](http://www.w3.org/TR/1999/REC-xslt-19991116#function-document)** and the standard XPath 2.0 function **[`tokenize()`](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-functions/#func-tokenize)**

Comment: thanks. Saxon is giving this error: "NotSpecified: (No source file name:String) [], RemoteException". Also, my xml files have other elements in that I want reproduced in the output (they are the same in file 'a' and file 'b'), will this approach still work in that case? (and sorry if that was vital info I should have put in the question)

Comment: @JackDouglas, If you simply create the files with the given filepaths and filenames and run this transformation with Saxon 9 (or any other compliant XSLT 2.0 processor), you must get the same result that I got (using Saxon 9.1.07) and copied and pasted the result in this answer. As for having new requirements that aren't specified in the question, I strongly recommend that you ask a new, separate question and describe them completely there. In its current form your question has been completely answered. The short answer is that any non-referenced element from FileB is copied to the output.

Comment: I have done that (except changing the path names) and I get the same error—is it possibly because I'm using the .NET variant and you are using the Java variant? I don't know. I trust that it *is* working for you however, and I'm delighted because I've been able to adapt your answer to get what I want. Thanks a million!

Comment: @JackDouglas, You are welcome. I can't say what is the error unless I can see your code. Glad you have been able to adapt this solution to your needs.

Answer (score -1):

While XSLT can output plain text, the input document is expected to be XML.  However, it's possible to mix in Java in your transformation.  Personally, I'd add some java functions to open the file and process it in a **grep**-like fashion.

This general [tutorial on adding Java functions to XSLT stylesheets](http://cafeconleche.org/books/xmljava/chapters/ch17s03.html) would be a good start.  It has the advantage of mentioning how-to's for some of the more common XSLT processing engines.

[Here's a related discussion on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9925483/calling-java-from-xsl-saxon)

Comment: I'm expecting the input document to be either xml file 'a' or xml file 'b'?

Comment: Sure, that's fine.  You can include subsequent XML files by using the document() function.  This thread http://stackoverflow.com/questions/648578/xslt-document-function-question has some useful information.

Comment: Not true for XSLT 2.0. Using the standard `unparsed-text()` function one can read any text file.

Comment: Right you are about XSLT 2.0.  I would point out, however, that apart from Saxon, many of the popular processing engines (e.g. libxslt) only support XSLT 1.0.